# How to compare existing field with an incoming update during a mongo query?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, orm, nosql

I have a doc for example

user doc

```
{
  name: "John"
}
```

and I want to update the name field to "Alex", but I want to be able to send some events with previous and new values to a 3rd party tracking software. Currently, I am using a simple `findByIdAndUpdate`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, in the event of update, your code have the current value (being sent to the query) and the query of `findByIdAndUpdate` returns the previous one

Comment: I am actually returning the updated doc with the `new` option

Comment: If you want to be able to send some events with previous and new values to a 3rd party tracking software - don't use the `new` option. You have all the 'new' data in your hand. No need to get it from the query. This is one reason why the `new` is not the default option

Comment: But I am using the updated response on the client, how do you recommend I should do it then? If I don't pass the `new` option, I get outdated data on the client

Comment: Your code is updating the db, hence your code holds the new data. No need to take it from the db which you are now updating

Comment: well, when I remove the `new` option, I get no update on the client, until I refresh the page

Comment: Think about it and try to understand what I'm saying. Who is sending the update to the client? Not the query itself...it is **your code** that handles the update event...

Comment: I am sending the return from the query `findByIdAndUpdate`